# How to compare list of lists with another list in Python?

Tags: python

```
a=[('3.25% GLN State Bank of India, London Br 2013-18.4.18 Global Sr Reg S (21163588)', '100,000.00', '100,040.00', '-1,755.00', '-1.72%'), ('Uts Muz ShortDur Acc.Units Class -R- Hedged USD (11851008)', '3,750.00', '463,500.00', '14,252.14', '+3.17%'), ('Shs PIMCO Income Accum.Shs Class -E- USD (20152466)', '48,433.,074', '655,783.82', '54,814.53', '+9.12%'), ('7.625% NTS Trafigura Group Pte Ltd 2013-WFM C red. 19.4.18 at 100% (21144967)', '200,000.00', '204,574.31', '28,310.00', '+16.44%'), ('2.5% NTS Glencore Funding LLC 2013-15.1.19 Reg-S Senior (21488623)', '160,000.00', '159,432.00', '26,376.00', '+19.82%'), ('6.25% NTS Deutsche Bank AG 2014-Without Fixed Mat Variable Rate Reg-S (24513566)', '400,000.00', '401,846.01', '15,420.00', '+4.05%')]
```

and

```
b=['Shs PIMCO Income Accum.Shs Class -E- USD (20152466)', '48,433.,074', '655,783.82', '54,814.53', '+9.12%']
```

how to compare these two lists?

```
for list1 in list2:
    return True
```

if I above thing by passing any other element in b that is not there in list then also it passes True.

Comment: What is your expected output? A simple True or False to indicate is there any common element? Or a list of True or False for each element in list1?

Comment: the community likes easy / small exemples instead of big chunks so could you please change the big strings for an easier exemple? We can't really see your problem because we get lost in your big bloc of data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking for method to compare a and b and should return true or false at the end

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to check that one list of `a` is the list `b`, you should test `b in a`.

However, this will return `False` since `a` is a list of tuples and `b` is a list. Then, you have three solutions:

- Change `a` into a list of list (change the `(.)` by `[.]`)
- Change `b` into a tuple `b=('Shs PIMCO Income Accum.Shs Class -E- USD (20152466)', '48,433.,074', '655,783.82', '54,814.53', '+9.12%')`
- Do not change the input data and use `tuple(b) in a` (this will cast `b` into a tuple before the test)